# How to get and set function using inside mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to use if condition inside schema creation,
    my schema is,

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var testSchema = new Schema({
      "Name":String,
      "TestValue":String
    }, {
      collection: 'test'
    });

    testSchema.eachPath(function(path) {   
             console.log(path);
    });

    testSchema.path('TestValue').set(function(value) {
        console.log("value: " + value);
        value="FFF";
        this.TestValue = value;
        return value;
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('test', testSchema);
```

I have to change TestValue based on the if condition,how to solve the problem...pls give me some solution to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.  Here are a couple:

```
testSchema.path('TestValue').set(function(value) {
    if (value === 'uh oh') {
        return 'a different value';
    } else {
        return value;
    }
});
```

Or you can use a ternary if you're so inclined:

```
testSchema.path('TestValue').set(function(value) {
    return (value === 'uh oh') ? 'a different value' : value
});
```

Comment: but the above code not working in my model class file...pls give some idea

Comment: cannot call set function

Comment: testSchema.path('TestValue').set(function(value) { return (value === '123') ? '111' : value }); i get below output, [{"Name":"AA","TestValue":"123"},{"Name":"BB","TestValue":"456"},{"Name":"CC","T‌​estValue":"789"}] but i have expect the below response, [{"Name":"AA","TestValue":"111"},{"Name":"BB","TestValue":"456"},{"Name":"CC","T‌​estValue":"789"}]

Comment: I tested it with this code http://www.hastebin.com/wulehekewo.coffee and everything worked correctly.